# How to emulate take_until_and_consume in nom 5.x?

Tags: rust, nom

I've updated my `nom` dependency from 4.x to 5.x version and found that macro `take_until_and_consume` is deprecated. Changelog says:

> "this can be replaced with `take_until` combined with `take`"

but I don't know how to emulate `take_until_and_consume` with them. 
Has anyone encountered such a problem with version updating or does anyone know how to do this?

I mean this deprecated macro [`take_until_and_consume`](https://docs.rs/nom/4.2.3/nom/macro.take_until_and_consume.html). And these new: [`take`](https://docs.rs/nom/5.1.1/nom/macro.take.html) and [`take_until`](https://docs.rs/nom/5.1.1/nom/macro.take_until.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is straiforward but here a generic implementation:

```rust
fn take_until_and_consume<T, I, E>(tag: T) -> impl Fn(I) -> nom::IResult<I, I, E>
where
    E: nom::error::ParseError<I>,
    I: nom::InputTake
        + nom::FindSubstring<T>
        + nom::Slice<std::ops::RangeFrom<usize>>
        + nom::InputIter<Item = u8>
        + nom::InputLength,
    T: nom::InputLength + Clone,
{
    use nom::bytes::streaming::take;
    use nom::bytes::streaming::take_until;
    use nom::sequence::terminated;

    move |input| terminated(take_until(tag.clone()), take(tag.input_len()))(input)
}

#[test]
fn test_take_until_and_consume() {
    let r = take_until_and_consume::<_, _, ()>("foo")(&b"abcd foo efgh"[..]);
    assert_eq!(r, Ok((&b" efgh"[..], &b"abcd "[..])));
}
```